# Chrome crashes Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: google-chrome, 17.10

I'm having an issue where chrome 65.0.3325.146 64-bit official build is crashing and freezing my system. This is on a clean install of 17.10.

Specifically, it's crashing whenever I visit the Authy app in the chrome store.

I've not had this problem with anything else in chrome, yet. Has anyone any thoughts/suggestions on the problem and how to fix?

Comment: You can start the Google Chrome from command line and see the messages after crash, maybe there's more info about the cause of crash.

Comment: I did it but nothing was informed about errors, just freezes

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be having the same problem, when i am playing videos in ubuntu 17.10, on both youtube and amazon prime, everything will be fine and then all the sudden chrome will freeze the entire os, yet playback works just fine with firefox on same sites...it happens otherwise but the best way to guarantee a crash is to start playing videos within 10 minutes i will be forced to do the alt-prtscreen-b keyboard combination to force linux to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue since 2 weeks. Every time it happens when I switch tabs in Chrome, it totally halts my mouse and keyboard.

It seems nothing to do with available RAM(usage < 60% and no swap occupied) but maybe related to currently opened web pages. In my case most of times I was on Google cloud console or Youtube.